Office Plugin - VB.NET - ExcelWorkbook.FullName Yet Again Returns a URL Instead of a Physical Path
I have a excel plugin that is using the following property:

ExcelWorkbook.FullName

As well documented in VBA, it's doing the same thing in my VB.NET office plugin, returning a URL instead of a physical path. Of course this fails when referenced in other parts of my application as they depend on a physical path being provided not a URL.
Much has been written about potential solutions in VBA, however I've yet to come across a solution that will work in a office plugin. Adapting the linked code solutions also comes with issues due to the libraries involved being different in VB.NET.
Is there a solution to this issue specifically coded in VB.NET, I'm would really like a single method that you could call such as this.

Could you adjust the "other parts of my application" to work with the URL directly?

@AndrewMorton If I could I wouldn't post this, I instruct my users to "Disable Autosave" to work around this issue, it's a pretty poor experience honestly...

Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim excelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
        Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = 
            excelApp.Workbooks.Open("YourWorkbookPath")
        
        Dim localPath As String = GetLocalPath(workbook.FullName)
        Console.WriteLine(localPath)
        
        ' Clean up
        workbook.Close(False)
        excelApp.Quit()
    End Sub

    Function GetLocalPath(fullPath As String) As String
        Dim fso As Object = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Return fso.GetAbsolutePathName(fullPath)
    End Function
End Module


I don't have the "YourWorkbookPath" because my plugin is running in a file that has already been opened by the user(this is in a office plugin), attempting to use the "GetLocalPath" method on "ExcelWorkbook.FullName" resulting is a malformed combination of the URL and a incorrect default one drive path..

Ok so I adapted the answer provided by @GWD here into VB.NET with a few minor changes to get it to work on my system:
Public Function GetLocalWorkspacePath()
    If (ExcelWorkbook.FullName.StartsWith("http")) Then
        Dim pathToReturn As String = ExcelWorkbook.FullName
        Dim subKeys As New List(Of String)
        Dim registryPath As String = "Software\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive\"

        Using key As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(registryPath)
            If key IsNot Nothing Then
                subKeys.AddRange(key.GetSubKeyNames().OrderByDescending((Function(subKey) key.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("UrlNamespace", String.Empty).ToString().Length)))

                For Each subKey In subKeys
                    Dim urlNamespace = key.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("UrlNamespace", String.Empty).ToString()
                    If ExcelWorkbook.FullName.Contains(urlNamespace) Then
                        Dim mountPoint = key.OpenSubKey(subKey).GetValue("MountPoint", String.Empty).ToString()
                        Dim secPart = ExcelWorkbook.FullName.Substring(urlNamespace.Length).Replace("/", "\")
                        pathToReturn = mountPoint & "\" & secPart

                        Do Until IO.Directory.Exists(pathToReturn) Or secPart.IndexOf("\", 1) = -1
                            secPart = secPart.Substring(secPart.IndexOf("\", 1))
                            pathToReturn = mountPoint & "\" & secPart
                        Loop

                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        End Using

        Return pathToReturn
    Else
        Return ExcelWorkbook.FullName
    End If
End Function

I feel this is sort of risky as I'm doing allot of find replace and iterative testing of the path to find a match, it would seem if you have files with the same name in a nested folder structure that you could run into some issues here. I may spend some time to further improve it but it mostly works for now.
